# Calling a function from an attempt to create a namespace and namespace is 'undefined'

Tags: jquery, namespaces

I was looking at how to create a namespace in Jquery and create a kind of a class that one would create in C#, I read through this [article](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/04/27/javascript-namespaces-and-modules/) and came up with this in a seperate JS file

```
var GlobalScript = {
    myStuff: function(){
        alert("hi");
    }
}
```

and I have tried calling the function like this in another external file..

```
$("#btnSave").click(function(){
    GlobalScript.myStuff();
});
```

and when it gets called I am getting an error in saying that it undefined, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine: [Demo](http://jsbin.com/niviberoye/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @aldanux, I see that it works when it is all in the same area, but the code is in seperate files.

Comment: I guess that you have then a [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) problem

Comment: @RachelGallen, I have looked over the article again, I am not an expert with JavaScript and not quite a newbie with it either. The project I have on the go right now, i have alot of duplicated code and having a hard time trying to fix it all to follow the DRY principle and so this way of working with JavaScript/JQuery is new to me, but not new to me with C#. So I guess I am pretty lost at the moment

Comment: @aldanux: There's no hoisting in the quoted code at all.

Comment: @Chris: It doesn't matter if they're in different files, as long as your `var GlobalScript...` line is at global scope and the file it's in is loaded as of when that button is clicked. If it's *not* at global scope, that's the problem.

Comment: @Chris: [This works](http://pastie.org/10891107), for instance.

Comment: @RachelGallen, I have no idea why it won't work on my end

Comment: Wow, my project must be a mess then because its just not working for me

Comment: I have a layout page that loads a bunch of scripts, then when a navigation button is clicked it loads a view, then when you click a button in the newly loaded view's toolbar, it opens a popup to add a new record with. I looked over my referencing and placed the Global script in the view that pops up then I get an error stating a token error +. So I guess I can be left with forgetting about what I am attempting and just initiate DRY principles by placing duplicated code into one script and just call it that way

Comment: http://www.rachelgallen.com/gs.html fyi working code

Comment: @RachelGallen: In that setup, the OP's code works too.

Comment: If either of you has TeamViewer or Skype and feels like taking a look at my code and doing some problem solving, then I would be ok with that. It could be fun (haha)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder here's why my approach is better than OPs - http://www.rachelgallen.com/gs2.html (what happens when there are 2 functions in GlobalScript using your/OPs approach) vs http://www.rachelgallen.com/gs3.html (works fine)

Comment: @Chris make a full fiddle or pastebin and share a link to code

Comment: @RachelGallen, I'll do my best, its going to take me awhile, once i have it done then I'll paste the link to it

Comment: @RachelGallen: I don't know what you're trying to say. http://www.rachelgallen.com/gs2.html just has a basic syntax error.

Comment: @RachelGallen, I got it all working now

Comment: @Chris - excellent! well done :)

Comment: @RachelGallen, thank you very much for sticking in with me. What was happening was that I had some erroneous code in the Global script and once i removed it everything started working properly

Comment: @RachelGallen, of course

Comment: @Chris hurrah now i come up as 12.8k (i'm 12750 - once you reach 50, it's rounded up :) )

Answer (score 0):

try this. Put the following code in your external file

```
function GlobalScript() {

    this.myStuff = function() {
       alert('hi');
    }
}
```

and then put this in your onclick

```
var my_obj = new GlobalScript();
my_obj.myStuff(); // should hopefully alert "hi"!
```

Comment: I still get the GlobalScript as undefined

Answer (score -1):

Everything looks fine. Are you sure that you included the separate file correctly?